# Intermittent Net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET Error and Incomplete Loading over HTTPS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis, f5

I have an F5 load balancing setup configured with two servers. My MVC web application, which incorporates Kendo UI, jQuery, and Bootstrap, is hosted on an IIS server with an SSL certificate. However, when accessing the application via HTTPS from outside the server, it often or sometimes results in a 'net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET' error, with intermittent failures to load JavaScript and CSS files to the client. Strangely, upon reloading the page, the assets load properly, and the page functions as expected. This issue did not occur when the application was accessed via HTTP, where it worked properly without any issues. What could be the reason behind this problem?
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: You posted a question here prematurely. Since you have a specific network setup, the very first task should be working with your network engineers (or support team) to trace down the TCP RESET packet source. Only when you know of that, further discussion can be made upon the network itself, IIS, or something. In general, such rarely ended up with programming so off topic here.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for your response. I appreciate your insight into tracing down the TCP RESET packet source in our network setup.However, I wanted to ask if you could provide any specific tips or best practices for tracing down the source of TCP RESET packets. Are there any particular tools or techniques you would recommend for this task?

Comment: That's why such questions are off topic here. You rarely see developers using network specific tools (Wireshark, tcpdump, etc) and that's what network administrators do.

Comment: @LexLi I am getting TCP RST from a remote system. How should I proceed?

Comment: Like I commented earlier, you do need help from someone knowing the network topology very well to assist. That's usually your network administrator(s) and no one else is able to help much.

Comment: @LexLi My web application functioned properly after turning off HTTP/2 in iis. I didn't get that error. for what reason?

Comment: HTTP/2 or HTTP/3 are new in the market, so maybe some devices on the wire are too old to properly support them (which shouldn't be a surprise I think).